# PTIJ: Why do we want the Hobbit to return?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Why are we so focused on the return of the hobbit? Some were sent across the sea to get him ([Kings I 8:43](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.18.43?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi))

> וַיֹּאמֶר אֶל־נַעֲרוֹ עֲלֵה־נָא **הַבֵּט** דֶּרֶךְ־יָם - He said to his servant, "Go up to the hobbit by way of the sea

other times we ask for him to be sent from Heaven ([Tehillim 80:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.80.15?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi))

> אֱלֹקים צְבָאוֹת שׁוּב־נָא **הַבֵּט** מִשָּׁמַיִם - Almighty please
> return the hobbit from Heaven

and twice a week in [Tachanun](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Post_Amidah%2C_Tachanun%2C_V%27hu_Rachum.4?vhe=Daat_Siddur_Ashkenaz&lang=bi) we plead for him

> הַבֶּט נָא רַחֶם נָא עַל עַמְךָ מְהֵרָה - please [send us the] hobbit,
> have mercy on your people!

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5):

וַיּוֹצֵא אֹתוֹ הַחוּצָה וַיֹּאמֶר הַבֶּט נָא הַשָּׁמַיְמָה וּסְפֹר הַכּוֹכָבִים אִם תּוּכַל לִסְפֹּר אֹתָם וַיֹּאמֶר לוֹ כֹּה יִהְיֶה

Translation: 
*God took him outside, and said: Hobbit, please [go] to the heavens and count [the divination of] the stars. When [and how] you will be able to complete the count, He said, so it will be.*

The Hobbit went to the heavens to count the stars, per God's command, and we are all eagerly awaiting for him to finish his holy task, so we can know what will happen in the end of days.

Answer (score 5):

We eagerly await the coming of The Hobbit, who will build G-d’s Tabernacle upon his return.

As [the famous song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSVipK7HaEY) goes:

> בלבו בי משכן אבנה
>
> [Bilbo B.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilbo_Baggins): “I will build a Tabernacle”.